# Wann braucht ein Satzteil ein Pronominaladverb?

Tags: sentence-structure, pronominal-adverb

Ich weiß nicht, wie man diese Frage mit Worten klar erklären würde, also fange ich mit Beispielen an.

> (1) Meine Mama hat mich **darum** gebeten, Dir ihre E-Mail-Adresse zu geben.
>
> (2) Ich freue mich **darauf**, mit euch zu reisen.
>
> (3) Wie wäre es **damit**, wenn Sie mich mal nicht unterbrechen würden?

1: Für mich und mein unraffiniertes Sprachgefühl klingt dieser Satz OK, aber muss man das *darum* einschließen oder kann man es auslassen?

2: Hier ist es für mich offenbar, dass man das *darauf* haben muss.

3: Über diesen Satz habe ich nicht viel nachgedacht. Wegen des Ausdrucks „Was wäre es mit …“ habe ich einfach angenommen, dass das *damit* unbedingt nötig ist; aber jemand hat mir gesagt, dass

> „Wie wär’s, wenn Sie mich mal nicht unterbrechen würden?“

besser klingt.

Also, wann muss man in diesem Zusammenhang ein Pronominaladverb benutzen und wann kann es ausgelassen werden?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Antwort hängt im Allgemeinen davon ab, ob das Verb eine Präposition verlangt oder nicht. Manche Verben können mit und ohne Präposition gebildet werden, wobei sich aber möglicherweise (leicht) verschiedene Bedeutungen ergeben.

## bitten

Hier gibt es die beiden Formen

> jemanden *um* etwas bitten
> jemanden bitten etwas zu tun

Die Bedeutung ist leicht verschieden, wird aber identisch, wenn das Objekt, *um* das man bittet, eine Handlung ist. Diese objektivierte Handlung kann grammatikalisch auf zwei Weisen gebildet werden:

- als Substantivierung oder Substantivableitung (würde hier nach Beamtendeutsch klingen)
- als erweiterten Infinitiv mit zu, der durch ein `darum` im Hauptsatz vertreten werden muss

Es ist also der Satz mit und ohne `darum` möglich, allerdings aufgrund verschiedener Versionen des Verbs `bitten`, die in diesem Fall jedoch gleichbedeutend sind.

## sich freuen

Auch hier gibt es die beiden Formen

> sich auf etwas freuen
> sich freuen, etwas zu tun

Syntaktisch verhält sich dieses Verb vollkommen analog zu `bitten`. Allerdings haben diese beiden Versionen des Verbs verschiedene Bedeutungen. `sich auf etwas freuen` bezieht sich auf zukünftige Ereignisse, `sich freuen, etwas zu tun` bezieht sich auf gegenwärtige Ereignisse (ließe sich auch auf zukünftige Handlungen beziehen, wenn man den Futur Infinitiv verwendet).

Aus diesem Grund kann man das `darauf` hier nicht weglassen, ohne die Bedeutung zu verändern.

Der genau gleiche Effekt wie bei `bitten` ergibt sich, wenn man `sich über etwas freuen` und `sich freuen, etwas zu tun` vergleicht.

## Wie wäre es (mit)

Der Fall ist ein bisschen komplizierter, weil es ein idiomatischer Ausdruck ist. Trotzdem gibt es auch hier beide Versionen:

> Wie wäre es damit, wenn …
> Wie wäre es, wenn …

Der Unterschied liegt darin, dass die erste Version im Allgemeinen einen ernstgemeinten Vorschlag als versteckte Bitte darstellt, während die zweite Version lediglich eine theoretische Überlegung darstellt. In deinem Beispiel ist die zweite Version allerdings leicht ironisch, sodass sich auch wieder die gleiche Bedeutung ergibt. Die zweite Version ist indirekter und deswegen unter Umständen eher zu empfehlen. Pauschalisieren wie dein Jemand würde ich hier aber nicht.